# Java class variable scope problem

Tags: java

I have this code(class in class) in java (andorid)

```
public class History extends Activity {

public Integer Type;

 private static class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      //I don't know how to access variable "Type" here
     Integer num = Type;// error
       .
       .
       .
     }
      .
      .
      .
```

}

I can't add more classes above "extends BaseAdapter"

Can someone help me, how can I access variable Type in class HistoryAdapter

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you "can't add more classes above `extends BaseAdapter`?  And you cannot access instance fields from another class without an instance of the outer class (`History`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HistoryAdapter` is a static class, which means that it doesn't have access to its parent class `History`. You'll either need to not make it not static (if possible), or you need to have the parent class pass the value of `Type` in through a helper function.

Example:

```
public class History extends Activity {
    public Integer Type;

    private static class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Integer num;

        HistoryAdapter(Integer num) {
            this.num = num;
       }
    }

    void foo() {
        HistoryAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(Type);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class History extends Activity {

public Integer Type;

 private class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     Integer num = Type;
       .
       .
       .
     }
      .
      .
      .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inner class needs access to the fields of the containing class, it has to not be `static`... then it will have that access. Alternatively, you can just give `HistoryAdapter` a constructor that takes an `Integer type` and pass the type from `History` to it when you create it.

Also, please don't capitalize the first letter of fields or variables in Java.